# How to display Icons with the styled-component icons that are hidden even after being inserted into the component? (GATSBY)

Tags: javascript, css, icons, gatsby, styled-components

I'm trying to show the icons in the aside. Below is the styled-components code and the way in which its logic was organized but the icons are not being shown by default.  a curious behavior is that if I write anything directly next to the icon component it start to display it but in different sizes.

MenuBar Component

index.js

```
import React from 'react';


import { Home } from '@styled-icons/material-rounded/Home'
import { Search } from '@styled-icons/icomoon/Search'
import { Lightbulb } from '@styled-icons/fa-solid/Lightbulb'
import { Grid } from '@styled-icons/boxicons-solid/Grid'
import { ToTop } from '@styled-icons/boxicons-solid/ToTop'

import * as S from './styled'

const MenuBar = () => (
  <S.MenuBarWrapper>
    <S.MenuBarGroup>
      <S.MenuBarLink to="/" title="Back to Home">
        <S.MenuBarItem><Home /></S.MenuBarItem>
      </S.MenuBarLink>
      <S.MenuBarLink to="/search/" title="Search">
        <S.MenuBarItem><Search /></S.MenuBarItem>
      </S.MenuBarLink>
    </S.MenuBarGroup>
    <S.MenuBarGroup>
      <S.MenuBarItem title="Change Theme"><Lightbulb /></S.MenuBarItem>
      <S.MenuBarItem title="Change Visualization"><Grid /></S.MenuBarItem>
      <S.MenuBarItem title="Go to Top"><ToTop /></S.MenuBarItem>
    </S.MenuBarGroup>
  </S.MenuBarWrapper>
)

export default MenuBar
```

styled.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'

export const MenuBarWrapper = styled.aside`
  align-items: center;
  background: #192734;
  border-left: 1px solid #38444d;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.8rem 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 3.75rem;
`

export const MenuBarGroup = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`

export const MenuBarLink = styled (Link)`
  display: block;
`
export const MenuBarItem = styled.span`
  display:block;
  color: #8899a6;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1.1rem;
`
```

[MenuBar aside without showing icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CPZQ.png)

When i type some text near the component:

[MenuBar aside showing icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL5y7.png)

Comment: can you make sure to set a width to the icon ? maybe without text, it doesn't know there's something ?

Comment: @windmaomao setting the width solved the problem! Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use material icon library. (Not material ui icon) . Very big library and has props for changing size by em size and fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the tip sajjadatma. Setting the width of the icon also solved the problem.